# How to get grep exit code without affecting standard output of piped command

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pacman-package-manager

I have this function:

```
psyu() {
    sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm | grep -q 'non ci sono aggiornamenti'
    [ $? != 0 ] &&
        notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Packages upgraded" ||
        notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Nothing to upgrade or there was an error"
}
```

(I'm Italian so I check for the Italian translation of "there are no updates". I don't know how else to do this because pacman does not have different exit codes for different cases.)

I want the command output to be normal in the terminal *(visualize all the pacman stdout)*, but I also want to use grep for the function to work.

Let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you intend to get, if `[ $? = 0 ]` is true and if not?

Comment: `foo && bar || baz` is not the same as `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`. Do not use it as a substitute.

Answer (score 3):

Forward the output to stdout with temporary file descriptor. Using `$?` is unneeded, just put the pipeline in the `if`.

```
{
if 
    sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm |
    tee >(cat >&3) |
    grep -q 'non ci sono aggiornamenti'
then 
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Packages upgraded"
else
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Nothing ..."
fi
} 3>&1
```

or maybe cleaner:

```
if {
       sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm |
       tee >(cat >&3) |
       grep -q 'non ci sono aggiornamenti'
   } 3>&1
then 
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Packages upgraded"
else
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Nothing ..."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` to duplicate `pacman`'s standard output and redirect one of the copies to the controlling tty of the current process; which, on Linux, is available as `/dev/tty`:

```bash
sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm |
  tee /dev/tty |
  if grep -q 'non ci sono aggiornamenti'; then
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Nothing ..."
  else
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Packages upgraded"
  fi
```

Alternatively, you may use `checkupdates` from [pacman-contrib](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman-contrib.git/about/). Its exit status is `2` when no updates are available:

```bash
checkupdates 1>/dev/null
if test "$?" -eq 2; then
  message="Nothing to upgrade or there was an error"
else
  sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm
  message="Packages upgraded"
fi
notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png -- "$message"
```

Note that in both your function and the first of my code snippets, one of the `if` branches (or one of the commands in your AND/OR list) is *always* executed, giving you a misleading notification when `pacman` terminates with an error.
To also account for that you need to send a copy of `pacman`'s output to a temporary file, because you can not catch `pacman`'s exit status *and* consume (`grep`) its output in the same pipeline:

```bash
psyu () (
  set -o pipefail
  trap 'rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT
  tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
  tmpfile="$tmpdir/pacman.out"
  if ! sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm |
    tee -- "$tmpfile"
  then
    message="pacman: Some error occurred"
  elif grep -q -- 'non ci sono aggiornamenti' "$tmpfile"; then
    message="Nothing to upgrade"
  else
    message="Packages upgraded"
  fi
  notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png -- "$message"
)
```

The `pipefail` shell option is needed to allow the `if` test to also catch errors occurring in the first stage of the pipeline (its exit status would otherwise be that of the last command).
Finally, note that the function definition is in parentheses `()` in order to avoid setting traps and options in the calling shell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use awk here:

```
sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm|
  awk '1;/non ci sono aggiornamenti/{r=7};END{exit(r)}'
[ $? != 7 ] && notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Packages upgraded" ||
  notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/arch.png "Nothing to upgrade or there was an error"
```

The awk means: Print all lines from pacman (that is what the lone `1` does). If "non ci sono aggiornamenti" exists in the output, set `r=7`. At the end, terminate and return the exit code (7 if the match was found, 0 otherwise).

I used 7 there because it is quite unlikely that that error will be used to signal another common error, but it could be any non-zero value in principle.

Comment: Why would you use awk rather than bash's native pattern matching for that?

Comment: That is: `pacman_output=$(sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm); pacman_retval=$?; if [[ $pacman_output =~ "your substring here" ]]; then ...thing to do if the substring is found...; else ...thing to do if the substring is not found...; fi` -- then there's no confusion between the test of the return value and the test of the output (which should maybe a test of stderr instead, but that's the OP's problem).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, I see, you would put all the output in a variable. I just have a instinctive repulsion to that, but I think it is valid in this case, maybe worth your answer with that?